# Swift 3.0 "Cannot infer type on" this var

Tags: ios, swift, package, swift3

I have recently been updating one of my packages SwiftDDP to swift 3.0 as it has not been updated by the author as of yet. When updating it I have run into a compiler error which says "Could not infer type on onWebsocketError"

```
internal var onWebsocketError:(_:Error) -> () = {error in log.error("websocket error \(error)")}
```

Log is declared like so

```
let log = XCGLogger(identifier: "DDP")
```

Error is declared in the Swift Standard library

How would I changes onWebsocketError so that it could be inferred and why is onWebsocketError currently not working? Thanks

Comment: Depends on how you declared `log` and `error(_:)`. Please add more info.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same result. Some another context may be affecting. Please try to create a minimum project which can reproduce your issue, and show us whole code of it.